# Java.SpannableString. Изменение строки с сохранением визуальных изменений

Tags: java, android, строки

Нужно покрасить некоторые буквы `String` переменной, затем изменить её (дописав пару слов, например) и покрасить уже другие буквы, сохраняя при этом покраску предыдущих.
Как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Можно.

Берете список спанов через `getSpans()`, далее редактируете строку, потом записываете в строку новый набор спанов через `setSpan()` (предварительно можно очистить старые спаны через `removeSpan()`)

Comment: А не могли бы вы накидать примерный код, если не сложно? Так не очень понятно

Comment: Почитайте [статейку](https://habrahabr.ru/post/167343/)